# When does "requires" cause a compiler error

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider this code:

```
struct Bad {};

int main() {
    static_assert(requires(int n, Bad bad) { n += bad; });
}
```

Compiling with Clang 13 and `-std=c++20`, I get the following error:

```
<source>:5:48: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'Bad')
    static_assert(requires(int n, Bad bad) { n += bad; });
                                             ~ ^  ~~~
1 error generated.
```

But I would have expected the requires expression to return false and fail the `static_assert`.

If I rewrite this concept as a template constraint, I get the conditional compilation that I expect i.e. the compiler doesn't complain that there is no `operator+=` and the requires returns false.

Comment: Something something, non-dependent, something something, no sfinae. Requires expressions are still in that model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [notation from the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.req#6):

> If a requires-expression contains invalid types or expressions in its requirements, and it does not appear within the declaration of a templated entity, then the program is ill-formed.

So `requires` only gains this capability when it is in a template.

Comment: Does this mean I "should" wrap my requires in a templated lambda to get conditional compilation?  I put should in quotes since that sounds pretty ugly

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash: If you're not in a template, then the answer to whether some `requires` statement resolves or not is visible in the code. So why do you need to ask a question you already know the answer to?

Comment: ah just wondering if there was a better way.  i don't feel very confident with requires (yet)